# After migrate to PHP 7.0 i don't have image on my main page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, php-5.4, php-7, magento-1.7.0.1

can somebody help me, I migrate my magento 1.8 from php 5.4 to 7.0 and now have problem with show image on main page

[image]

Comment: Try flushing your catalog images cache and check media folder permission

Comment: Hello, i try flushing catalog images in admin panel but its didn't help me. For all media folder I have 777 permission but its stile not work :(